# How to make my maven jar to publicly available

Tags: java, maven, nexus

How to publish my jar to mavenrepository.com ?

Comment: Why should the general public be interested in your proprietary code?

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic ahh, I have one product, that needed this Jar as SDK. so I need this way.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [distributionManagement in Maven](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management).

> Distribution management acts precisely as it sounds: it manages the
>   distribution of the artifact and supporting files generated throughout
>   the build process.

The way you can use it is very well specified in the provided link yet a sample line of code would be something like -

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>release-artifactory</id>
        <name>RELEASE Artifactory</name>
        <url>http://artifactory.some.release.url</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshot-artifactory</id>
        <name>SNAPSHOT Artifactory</name>
        <url>http://artifactory.some.snapshot.url</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, its called OSSRH . Here is the link

http://central.sonatype.org/pages/ossrh-guide.html